# Emploi de "alea jacta est"

Tags: latin

Peut-on employer couramment l'expression latine **alea jacta est** ou l'expression française homologue **le dé en est jeté** pour dire
*la décision est prise ; l'action est lancée* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La traduction française est plus correctement [Les dés sont jetés](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/les_d%C3%A9s_sont_jet%C3%A9s) ou encore, et c'est dans celle-ci que « en » se trouve,  « Le sort en est jeté » ; soit dit en passant, cette dernière traduction, a toujours été plus littéraire et le reste, à mon avis ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+d%C3%A9s+sont+jet%C3%A9s%2Cle+sort+en+est+jet%C3%A9&corpus=19&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20d%C3%A9s%20sont%20jet%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20sort%20en%20est%20jet%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cles%20d%C3%A9s%20sont%20jet%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20sort%20en%20est%20jet%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)).
Voici la [comparaison des fréquences](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+d%C3%A9+en+est+jet%C3%A9%2Cles+d%C3%A9s+sont+jet%C3%A9s&corpus=19&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20d%C3%A9%20en%20est%20jet%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20d%C3%A9s%20sont%20jet%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20d%C3%A9%20en%20est%20jet%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20d%C3%A9s%20sont%20jet%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0) pour « le dé… » et  « les dés … ».
Oui, bien sur, vous pouvez utiliser la locution latine et dans un entourage de personnes très instruites vous ne passerez pas pour bizarre, déplacé ou prétentieux, pourvu que, comme le fait dire La Fontaine à un de ses animaux, votre ramage se rapporte à votre plumage.
Je présume qu'il est  plus courant d'utiliser le français dans des milieux moins littéraires et dans un contexte même familier, la version qui commence par « le sort » reste sans problème, mais elle est moins terre à terre.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, on peut.

J'ai plus l'habitude du pluriel :

> Les dés <s>en</s> sont jetés.

mais les deux formes existent, ainsi que

> Le sort en est jeté.

que LPH a justement inclus dans sa réponse.